# Vlook up from one table body range to another table body range

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables:

- tblCost1 which includes the cost for each product
- tblCost2 missing cost

I m targeting to get the cost from `tblCost1` and import it in `tblCost2`.

i use the below formula but i m missing something and i get the wrong figure.

`=VLOOKUP([@Product],tblCost1,tblCost1[Cost],2)`

Please see below table structure.

[image]

Comment: The third argument is the column number and the fourth should be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=VLOOKUP([@Product],tblCost1, 2, 0)
```

The third argument is the column number and the fourth should be zero

Comment: if i change the column index number to 2 it s works fine. What i m trying to find is how to use the column name instead of a number. i manage to find a solution using MATCH function. Thanks anyway for user answer.